# iOS: String who cannot be nil. How can I do?

Tags: swift

Fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
I checked that ticket that didn't help me:

[What does "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32170456/what-does-fatal-error-unexpectedly-found-nil-while-unwrapping-an-optional-valu)

```
  "CODE_SUPLEMENT7": form.csupplement7! != nil ? form.csupplement7! : "",
```

I try to avoid that mistake, but it says "Comparing non-optional value of type String to nil always return true."

How to find the good type String with the capability to accept the String ? (because my code is all based on it...)

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: change `form.csupplement7! != nil ? form.csupplement7! : ""` to `form.csupplement7 ??  ""`. You should google about the `??` nil coalescing operator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is your use of `!` just before the `!=`.

It should be:

```
form.csupplement7 != nil ? form.csupplement7! : ""
```

But even better is to use `??`:

```
form.csupplement7 ?? ""
```